# How to model a unidirectional relationship in JPA (Hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

What is the correct way to model the following relationship shown in the image?
[image]

The identifier of the entity **global_rating** is a *foreign key* (the id of the **provider entity**)

Remember that I need to do it in a unidirectional way, that is, the provider entity has a global_rating but global_rating does not have a provider.

Please, I need to know what is the correct way to model this in Java if I using Hibernate as ORM. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hibernate entity should have an Id. This id may be a column (even a primary key) in another table, but it should exist. So you need to add to globalRating entity Provider field or ProviderId field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
@Entity
public class Provider{
    @Id
    private String id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private GlobalRating globalRating;
}

@Entity
public class GlobalRating{
    @Id
    private String id;
}
```

You can read about it in the hibernate [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-association).